# Image reading and saving into a specific file

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with reading a .pgm image from a user-specified location. My problem is that the program runs but it doesn't read the image from the specified location. Would really appreciate some help. I have tried not deleting the arrays but the .pgm image that I am trying to read is still not being found by this code.I am wondering if there is something wrong with my code itself,or if there is something wrong with how I am trying to enter the image and save it.

```
    ...
//function to read the image
    void Image::readFile() {
        char c;
        cout << "The function call worked" << endl;
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(fileName + ".pgm", ios::binary);
        if (inFile)
        {
    
            inFile >> this->version;
            inFile >> this->width;
            inFile >> this->height;
            inFile >> this->numOfPixels;
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                delete[] pixels[i];
            }
            delete pixels;
    ...
    ...
    
            inFile.read(&c, 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    
                    inFile.read(&c, 1);
                    this->setPixels(j, i, static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    
                }
            }
    
            cout << version << endl;
            cout << height << " " << width << endl;
            cout << numOfPixels << endl;
    
            inFile.close();
            cout << "Closing the file" << endl;
    
        }
        else {
            cout << "File is not opened" << endl;
        }
    
    ...
    ...
    }
    
    void Image::saveImage(const string& newFileName) {
        ofstream outFile;
        outFile.open(newFileName + ".pgm", ios::binary);
        if (outFile.fail())
        {
            cout << "Output failed" << endl;
            return;
        }
    
        outFile << version << endl;
        outFile << height << " ";
        outFile << width << endl;
        outFile << numOfPixels << endl;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                outFile << static_cast<char>(pixels[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
        outFile.close();
        cout << "Closing the file" << endl;
    
    
    
    }
    ...
    ...
    Image::~Image() {
        cout << "Destruction of object!" << endl;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            delete[] pixels[i];
        }
        delete[] pixels;
    
    }
    ...
```

Comment: `"but the .pgm image that I am trying to read is still not being found by this code"` -- Are you saying that `if (inFile)` evaluates to `false` and that the line `cout << "File is not opened" << endl;` gets executed, so that you are seeing that error message?

Comment: yes,that is correct

Comment: What is the value and type of `fileName`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: filename is an input by the user as my teacher had given me several .pgm images.For example,one of them is barbara and bird etc.filename is string

Comment: Did you type `barbara`? Are these files in whatever folder is the current working directory as your program will not search at all. They must be in the current working directory and must be named exactly as the files are named.

Comment: What is the type of `fileName`? Is it of type `std::string`? Or is it a C-style string (null terminated `char` array)? Please show how it is declared. A [mre] would be best.

Comment: Can I get your email so I could send the file to you?

Comment: @AmritMukhi: Can't you simply create a very small program that does nothing else than read the filename from the keyboard, add the `.pgm` extension, and attempt to open that file, and print whether opening the file was successful or not? This would be a [mre] and should only be a few lines of code. Or can't you reproduce the error using such a small program?

Comment: Also make sure your file name exactly matches. This is important on windows because the file explorer by default hides the file extension on known types. That can cause serious confusion that may cause you to have 2 extensions or a different extension than you think.  In `c++` the filename (including extensions) must match exactly. Also the rest of the path must be correct.